# Firebase Cannot Register User

Tags: javascript, forms, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Firebase and I wanted to create a simple login form according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OKrloDzGpU).

I followed the instructions and copied the code line by line, with an exception for my config data and firebase version (I'm using 4.12.0 instead of 3.1 like in the video)

I got to the point where whatever I type into my login form (that is in valid email format) in console I only get `not logged in` instead of the user info. (tried both on localhost and after deployment)

Here's my code:

```js
(function(){
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    // here is my config info
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  //Get elements
  const txtEmail = document.getElementById('email');
  const txtPassword = document.getElementById('password');
  const btnSignIn = document.getElementById('sign-in');
  const btnSignOut = document.getElementById('sign-out');
  const btnSignUp = document.getElementById('sign-up');

  //Add login event
  btnSignIn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    //Get email and password
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const password = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    //Sign in
    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  });

  //Add signup event
  btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {
    //Get email and password
    // TODO check for real email
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const password = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    //Sign in
    const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  });

  //Add a real time listener
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
    if(firebaseUser){
      console.log(firebaseUser)
    } else {
      console.log('not logged in');
    }
  });
}());
```

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

form{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width:300px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);

}

input{
  margin: 5px 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border:none;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #d2d2d2;
  outline: 0;
  color: black;
  padding: 4px;
}

input:focus{
  border-bottom: solid 2px #66a2d0;
}

/* BUTTONS */

input, button{
  width:150px;
}

button{
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
}

button:hover{
  background-color:#ccc;
}

button#sign-in{
  background-color: #66a2d0;
}

button#sign-out{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <label>
      <p>Email</p>
      <input type="text" id="email" type="email" required />
    </label>
    <label>
      <p>Password</p>
      <input type="password" id="password" required />
    </label>
    <button id="sign-in">Sign In</button>
    <button id="sign-up">Sign Up</button>
    <button id="sign-out">Sign Out</button>
  </form>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have enabled email sign-in method. I don't see any new data being created inside my project.

I tried looking for the answer in the documentation but couldn't find any example as well explained as the one in the video.

So as I'm not very familiar with firebase I don't know where is the problem. Is it that the video is outdated and some of the functions do not work with the newer firebase version? Or is it something in my code / project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit the form, the event listener doesn't have time to process: the page reloads before that can happen.

You need to prevent the form from being submitted.

Try adding `e.preventDefault();` to your `btnSignUp` event listener like so:

```
 btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {
    //Get email and password
    // TODO check for real email
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const password = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    // Stop form from submitting and reloading the page.
    e.preventDefault();
    //Sign in
    const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  });
```

You should be able to see new users after.